# How to rewrite a static final field in jdk11?

Tags: java, java-11

In the past it was possible to change a `static final` field eg during a unit test as follows:

```
static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) {
    field.setAccessible(true);

    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    field.set(null, newValue);
  }
```

call with:

```
setFinalStatic(MyObject.class.getField("myfield"), "newval");
```

But as of Java 11 (or even before) that seems not to be possible anymore (the target field is not changed).

What are the chances now of forcing a static final field change?

I know this is kind of a hack. But in special cases, eg during a single junit test, this was the rescue for not having to import larger libraries like `PowerMock`.

Is it still possible today?

Comment: *"seems not to be possible anymore"* Why? What happens when you try?

Comment: @Andreas the static final  field that should change is simply not changed.

Comment: Are you possibly confused by the compiler inlining static final constant expressions (primitives, strings)? The static field may have changed, but it may not affect code using those fields as the original value has been inlined by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

What you should be using is `@PrepareForTest` from PowerMock; under the hood it uses [javassist](http://www.javassist.org/), which uses the Instrumentation API that will make it possible for you to mock whatever you had before.

Only the vanilla java way is gone from java-12, since that hack with `modifiers` will no longer work.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that the value under test was as follows:

```
class MyObject {
   public static final Boolean myfield = "true";
}
```

I don't know why, but change the field as follows now lets me change the field by reflection again:

```
 public static final Boolean myfield = Boolean.TRUE;
```

Comment: Well, a `static final String` is a constant expression, so it will be inlined.

Comment: The const expression stuff is the reason for it not changing. Bear in mind that the `modifiers` will not be accessible in java 12, so it'll stop working there as well. other workarounds are doing `myfield = new String("true")`, or putting the initialization into a `{}` block

Comment: Does `public static final myfield` even compile?

Comment: @Petesh fun fact: even with accessible modifiers, this hack wouldn’t work, if there wasn’t explicit code in `jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory` supporting this hack (still there in JDK 11). While at the same time, the JVM’s optimizer is allowed to take unchanging `static final` fields for granted…

Comment: @Petesh thanks for the info. Could you suggest a working solution that's still valid in jdk12+?

Comment: I can't really help you in this - It looks like the [powermock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/pull/955) folks just gave up on being able to do this as well.

Comment: It seems that the question changes its topic. Reflectively changing compile-time constants never worked, even in the very first Java version. Reflectively changing a `static final` field not being a compile-time constant was a hack that seemed to work in some situations (as said, the optimizer still could break it), but could be replaced by instrumenting the code that reads the field. That would reliably work in all JVMs supporting Instrumentation.

Comment: @Holger we rely sooo much on `Whitebox::setInternalState` that actually uses that trick of `modifiers`. I have just tried to switch to java-12 and ... nightmare in tests. do you happen to know if this is a certain JEP that was part of?

Comment: @Holger but there is `@PrepareForTest` in power mock that uses javassist that makes this pain go away... exactly like you said about instrumentation API.

Comment: @Eugene late answer but https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8210496 looks like the right point (delievered in JDK 12).

Comment: @membersound the old declaration surely wasn’t `… Boolean myfield = "true"`.